# My program isn't changing MySQL database yet presents no error

Tags: python, mysql

I've written a program to scrape a website for data, place it into several arrays, iterate through each array and place it in a query and then execute the query. The code looks like this:

```
for count in range(391):
    query = #long query
    values = (doctor_names[count].encode("utf-8"), ...) #continues for about a dozen arrays
    cur.execute(query, values)
cur.close()
db.close()
```

I run the program and aside from a few truncation warnings everything goes fine. I open the database in MySQL Workbench and nothing has changed. I tried changing the arrays in the values to constant strings and running it but still nothing would change.

I then created an array to hold the last executed query: `sql_queries.append(cur._last_executed)` and pushed them out to a text file:

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")

for q in sql_queries:
    fo.write(q)
fo.close()
```

Which gives me a large text file with multiple queries. When I copy the whole text file and create a new query in MySQL Workbench and execute it, it populates the database as desired. What is my program missing?

Comment: you need to call `cur.commit()`

Comment: It was actually `db.commit()` but thank you! If you want to mark it down as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is using a transactional storage engine, like Innodb, then you need to call `db.commit()` to have the transaction stored:

```
for count in range(391):
    query = #long query
    values = (doctor_names[count].encode("utf-8"), ...) 
    cur.execute(query, values)
db.commit()
cur.close()
db.close()
```

Note that with a transactional database, besides [comitting](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit) you also have the opportunity to handle errors by [rollingback](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rollback) inserts or updates with `db.rollback()`. The `db.commit` is required to finalize the transaction. Otherwise,

> Closing a connection without committing the changes first will cause
>   an implicit rollback to be performed.